# Unable to make julia package manager work behind proxy

Tags: git, proxy, julia

I realize that this may seem a duplicate question but the fact is that although it seems that I have configured the package manager to work behind proxy I am unable to install packages.

My settings are:

```
run(`git config --list`)
http.proxy=http://<correct_proxy_:<correct_port>
https.proxy=https://<correct_proxy_:<correct_port>
url.https://github.insteadof=git://github
```

Julia version is 0.5.0 on a linux (Ubuntu 16.04) machine

I have Julia version 0.3.1 installed on a windows machine and everything works fine with the same configuration.

Comment: What kind of error(s) are you getting?

Comment: ERROR: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, Failed to connect to github.com: Connection refused)
 in macro expansion at ./libgit2/error.jl:99 [inlined]
 .....

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar set-up. This is generally what i'll use:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@IP
git config --global https.proxy https://user:password@IP
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/
```

and you may also need this:

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@IP
export https_proxy=https://user:password@IP
```

Just make sure to clear your .gitconfig file out afterwords, as you are making your credentials known:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```